# Startup Script for LAMP in Google Instance Templates

Tags: apache, server, cloud

I am new to Google Cloud and i want to set up an Instance Template and then create an Instance Group using the template.

After creating the group, i want to enable "Network Load Balancing".

During Template creation, it asks for startup scripts. I checked online and found the following script.

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y apache2
```

I want to use Apache, PHP and MySql (with PHPMyAdmin) on the cloud. So i added some more scripts in it. The script i created is this:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo apt-get install -y apache2
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server
sudo apt-get install -y phpmyadmin
```

But when i create an Instance Group, there is no access to PhpMyAdmin and not even the IP Address shows server not found.

Can anyone help me setup Google Cloud?